# How to zoom only content of RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a custom RecyclerView that zooms, but when I zoom in, the entire RecyclerView zooms in and I cannot scroll to the borders of the view because they are off the screen. How do I only zoom the content of the view and not the view itself?

Code for ZoomRecyclerView:

```
public class ZoomRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
private ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector;
private static final String TAG = ZoomRecyclerView.class.getSimpleName();

private float scaleFactor = 1.f;
private static final float minScale = 1.0f;
private static final float maxScale = 3.0f;

public ZoomRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(getContext(), new ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            scaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

            //makes sure user does not zoom in or out past a certain amount
            scaleFactor = Math.max(minScale, Math.min(scaleFactor, maxScale));

            //refresh the view and compute the size of the view in the screen
            invalidate();

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    super.onTouchEvent(event);

    //notify the scaleGestureDetector that an event has happened
    scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

    return true;
}

@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
    //scales the display, centered on where the user is touching the display
    canvas.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, scaleGestureDetector.getFocusX(), scaleGestureDetector.getFocusY());

    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
}
}
```